# Setting spellcheck language for textbox WITHOUT changing keyboard language possible?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, keyboard, spell-checking

I am using C# & .Net 4.0 and want to set the a differnet spellcheck language for a textbox without changing the keyboard layout.

I found out by reading great postings here that it is possible to change InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage for changing the SpellCheck language of my textbox. But this has the sideeffect, that the keyboard layout/language was changed too. But **I need always an EN SpellCheck for my textbox without crashing the users keyboard settings**. Is there any way for this case?

Thanks in Advance for every hint that can help me to solve this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found out, how to solve it.

You have to know, that I use the WPF TextBox in a Winforms project. Here is a sample code:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost elementHost1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost();
System.Windows.Controls.TextBox textBox = new System.Windows.Controls.TextBox();
textBox.Language = System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("en-GB");
textBox.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;
elementHost1.Child = textBox;
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the language using textBox.Language didn't work for me.

There seems to be an edge case where spell checking is completely disabled if the user's presently selected input language doesn't have the spelling dictionary installed for that language (i.e. the feature-on-demand language pack is missing for basic typing) - see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/features-on-demand-language-fod

Take the following example:

• the user's current selected language/keyboard is fr-FR

• the user doesn't have the "basic typing" feature on demand installed for fr-Fr (no dictionary is therefore available)

• the user does have en-GB installed as well as "basic typing", so the dictionary is available for en-GB.

I wanted to force my textbox to spell check in en-GB, even though the user's keyboard was set to fr-FR.  (The reason for this is I'm actually piggy-backing off the WPF spell check feature to spell check an underlying document).

However, just setting the Language attribute in the textbox wasn't achieving that.  i.e. even when specifying en-GB for Language, the spell check wasn't available.

In the end, I had transiently to set the input language to the desired language, create the textbox, and then change it back to the user's existing input language.  This is therefore transparent to the user (i.e. as far as the user is concerned, it doesn't disturb their current input language).

```
InputLanguage original_language = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage;

System.Globalization.CultureInfo my_culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
InputLanguage c = InputLanguage.FromCulture(my_culture);
InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = c;

System.Windows.Controls.TextBox testBox = new System.Windows.Controls.TextBox();
testBox.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;
elementHost1.Child = testBox;

InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = original_language;
```

Note that, once the textbox has been created and bound to the elementHost, it doesn't matter if you change the input language back - the language of that textBox is permanently set to what it was when it was created.

Therefore, in the above example, the user would end up with the spell check working in British English, but still have his or her keyboard set to French.

In practice, there's extra code to the above to check that the language you're setting (en-GB in this case) is actually installed.