# Windows 8.1 / 10 App Spellcheck language

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, spell-checking, windows-8.1-universal

How do I set spell check language on a TextBox? 
I've tried this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" IsSpellCheckEnabled="True" Language="en-US" xml:lang="en-US" />
```

but no luck :(

with this I only get danish spell check.

(I'm using danish input language)

The app the targeted windows 8.1.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, you could change the keyboard language to make spellcheck work. Moreover, you could refer to this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736177/setting-spellcheck-language-for-textbox-without-changing-keyboard-language-possi) providing WPF sample for setting spellcheck language without changing keyboard language setting.

Comment: Yes, the change of keyboard langauge works but the code in your link in not able to work because PresentationCore (in PresentationCore.dll) where windows.markup is, does not exist in WinRT.

Comment: @MikkelGunvald you could submit this feature request in Feedback Hub, then MS might think about adding this feature in the future

Comment: @MessiKing Good idea, I will do that.

Answer (score 1):

If we want to implement the spell-check function without changing the keyboard input language, we can use this [Spell Checking (C#, VB, HTML5/JavaScript)](https://spellcheckiing.codeplex.com/) library which can be used for basic spelling checks and providing suggestions in Window Store App irrespective of Store App Language, for the detailed information, please check [this sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/SpellChecker-C-9cbafc40).

Comment: I will look into it. Thank you :)